# Non-unique prime factorisation

Tags: number-theory

G is a number system where $(a,b)$ belongs in G where $a$ and $b$ is an element of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$.

multiplication is defined as follows:

$(a, b) \times (c, d) := (ac-5bd , ad+bc)$

$(6,0)$ is one number that has non-unique prime factorisation.

Find two more numbers in G that each have non-unique prime factorisation.  One of your
numbers must of the form $(a, 0)$, and the other one of the
form $(a, b)$ where $b$ does not equal $0$ .

Basically I understand how $(6,0)$ has non-unique prime factorisation because

$(6,0) = (1,1) \times(1,-1)$ is one prime factorization

$(6,0) = (2,0) \times (3,0)$ is another prime factorization

But i need to find two more numbers like this but is there a certain method to finding more numbers like $(6,0)$ because I'm sure I'm not just supposed to do trial and improvement.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens if you replace $(6,0)=(1,1)*(1,-1)$ with $(z,z)*(z,-z)$?

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ If an element has a prime factorization (so unique) then so too does every divisor. Thus, contrapositively, if an element has a nonunique factorization, so too does all its multiples $\ne 0.$ (posted as a comment since the system will not allow answers for at least the last 10 minutes).

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange.com! That's a nice question. Looking for a method rather than a trick is the way to go. Note that the example is based on a number $(a,0)$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is composite. That should give you an idea how to make more examples of this sort. And the simple example of the second kind would be something like $(0,b)$. Can you produce such numbers as products?

Comment: Perhaps it helps noticing that you are really multiplying numbers of the form $a + b \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: $\sqrt{-5}$

Comment: @ccorn, of course, sorry. And thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If an element has a prime factorization (so unique) then so too does every divisor. Thus, contrapositively, if an element has a nonunique factorization, so too does all its multiples $\ne 0.$

Comment: The OP seems to mean *irreducible* where he says *prime*.

Comment: @ccorn Right, but maybe that is the terminology used in the OP's course (i.e. same terminology as in elementary number theory in $\,\Bbb Z).$